# How to extract portions of joda Date time effectively?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jodatime

I have a Joda Date Time object that contains date and time fields and I wish to extract the date and time portions into 2 different sql date and time objects (java.sql.). I thought converting the DateTime to milliseconds and storing it in the respective sql objects would do the trick however it produces calculation errors further upstream in my app logic as one is === to the other.

Comment: JodaTime has lots of methods for extracting parts.  Did you read the Javadoc?

Comment: yes. However the best I can think of to over come this was to extract the components into LocalDate/Time objects, push them back into separate dateTime objects before converting them back into sql date and Time. I want to know if there's an easier way.

Comment: You do realize that a `java.sql.Time` object is just a `java.sql.Date` wrapped with some formatting, right? It's still a date/time and not just an offset from midnight.

Comment: So what do you want the Time object to contain? Offset from midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I've found to do this so far is what I've described in my comment on the question and then convert back to sql time using:

```
new java.sql.Date(locDate.toDateTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).getMillis()));
new java.sql.Time(locTime.toDateTimeToday().getMillis()) );
```

Couldn't find anything in the DateTime object API to extract the respective parts.